# C interface for Mathematica

Tags: front-end, mathlink-or-wstp, interoperability

I would like to write a small C program which starts a Mathematica session, executes some user defined code and retrieves the output and finally quits the session. Basically I like to have a simple custom made user interface for Mathematica based on standard C. I am confident that such libraries exist since I am using a program of this kind for Maple (based on OpenMaple libraries). I just do not know where to start. Maybe somebody can point me to the documentation. Ideal would be a small sample application. Maybe something like this ships with Mathematica?

---

Don't be confused by the comments. Eventhough the answer "see the Documentation" seems obvious here (as I ask for it), the by far best resource for the solution is 
[on the Wolfram webpage](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/174/frontend.c?file_id=4692). See also my answer below. As far as I can see it is neither referenced in the documentation nor contained in the builtin examples. Not knowing the words to search for it took some effort to find it.

Comment: You've seen MathLink?

Comment: Sometimes I wonder why people not type "C program" or "C++" into the help browser in the first place. The documentation to ["C/C++ Language Interface"](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/CLanguageInterface.html) would have been always one of the first hits..

Comment: No questions, no answers, no question-answer game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found [this](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/174/frontend.c?file_id=4692) example front end; it is pretty much what I need. It compiles just like the factor example in the Mathematica Documentation in `$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/$SystemID`.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a link to some [MathLink documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MathLinkAndExternalProgramCommunicationOverview.html). You'll want section [Running Mathematica from Within an External Program](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/RunningMathematicaFromWithinAnExternalProgram.html) from that overview.

In it there is a line that states:

> The MathLink Developer Kit contains sample source code for several
>   simple but complete front ends.

You should be able to be up and running quickly using these examples.

The first page mentioned above also provides links to system-specific setup procedures, for instance about how to complete the installation of the necessary stuff that came with MMA's installation.

Comment: Thanks so far. I found it and made the factor "frontend" compile. What I miss now is a basic example for sending a string (presumably using MLPutString) and retrieving an output string. The examples I see mix sending/retrieving of various data types which I find a bit confusing.